# Google Calendar API - Getting events from server side stop working - Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I was retrieving all the events from a CalendarId managed by another user and showing them in our website using the server side library *Google.Apis.Calendar.** in .Net. It continues working well since a period of almost 2 month and suddenly stop working showing this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVAhp.png).
The thing is that the service account do have all permissions (View all details) in the calendar but stop working with no reason when executes the request (*request.Execute();*). Anyone who have a clue of this issue? I would really appreciate it.

```
public class GCalendarService : Service
{

    public GCalendarService(X509Certificate2 certificate, String accountName, String appName) : base(certificate, accountName, appName)
    {
        this.Scopes = new string[] {
            CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
            CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
        };
        this.InitializeCredential(certificate);
        this.GService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = this.Credential,
            ApplicationName = appName
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the events based on a period of time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="calendarId">The ID of the calendar to get the events</param>
    /// <param name="minDate">The minimun date to request</param>
    /// <param name="maxDate">The max date to request</param>
    /// <param name="maxEvents">The max amount of events to retrieve</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Object GetEvents(string calendarId, DateTime? minDate, DateTime? maxDate, int maxEvents) 
    {
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = ((CalendarService)this.GService).Events.List(calendarId);
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = maxEvents;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
        return request.Execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`404: Not Found`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found) that you get means that the specified resource was not found. Another possible cause is when the requested resource (with the provided ID) has never existed or when accessing a calendar that the user can not access.

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
       ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

The suggested action here is used [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff).

Regarding for the service account, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044564/google-calendar-service-account-with-php-api-oauth2-0-how-to-access-calendars) might help you. According to this, when accessing private calendar with a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority), you need to either perform an authority delegation if you own the domain containing those calendars or you will need to share the private calendar with the email address of the service account.

Comment: Hi @adjuremods, thanks so much for your fast response. The thing is that the service do have the permission needed in the calendard we need as you can see in this image [http://screencast.com/t/Qzu6P5rAp2ql]. Do you now if there is an extra configuration needed? because is crazy, it used to work for a while and just stop working without changing any code

Comment: After several tests I find out it must be a configuration from the side of the domain manager because only happens if the calendar is from someone in the domain, if I try with a different gmail account out of the domain and share it with the same service account it works perfectly.